# Solve a linear program in CPLEX without the cuts and preprocessing

Tags: c++, linear-programming, cplex

I'm willing to solve the linear relaxation of an ILP model I have.
Thus, I set all of my `{0,1}` variables as `IloNumVar` and called the function `solve()` of CPLEX.

However, this call solves the root node performing a costly preprocessing and inserting a lot of cuts, but all I want to do is to get the solution of the linear relaxation of my model.

I set all of the above parameters. However, the linear relaxation is not solved fastly enough due to the CPLEX preprocessing.

```cpp
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::Cliques, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::Covers, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::DisjCuts, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::FlowCovers, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::FlowPaths, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::GUBCovers, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::ImplBd, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::MIRCuts, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::FracCuts, -1);
cplex->setParam(IloCplex::ZeroHalfCuts, -1);
```

---

How can I get rid of this preprocessing and obtain the solution of the linear relaxation only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve the linear relaxation then you have to solve the model as an LP, not as a MIP. To do this, convert all variables to continuous variables. This can be done by adding an [IloConversion](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloConversion.html) for each variable. See for example function `solveRelaxed` in example `iloadmipex6.cpp` that is shipped with CPLEX:

```
void solveRelaxed(IloModel mdl, IloNumVarArray vars, IloNumArray rel) {
   IloEnv env = mdl.getEnv();
   IloModel relax(env);
   relax.add(mdl);
   relax.add(IloConversion(env, vars, ILOFLOAT));
   IloCplex cplex(relax);
   cplex.solve();
   env.out() << "Solution status = " << cplex.getStatus() << endl;
   cplex.getValues(rel, vars);
   cplex.end();
   relax.end();
}
```

Btw, a simpler way to disable all cutting planes is to set parameter `CutPass`.

Also note that even when solving as an LP CPLEX will do presolve. Presolve can be disabled via parameter `PreInd`.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Junglas. All my variables were linear. However, these parameters for turning off the cuts and the pre-solve worked very well for me :)